# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I fix the error of IndexOutOfBoundsException?
I am creating a quiz type application but its forces close whenever i finish answering the questions and proceed to the ResultActivity. 
Please help me. Thanks!

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
            }
            if(qid<5){                  
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}
}
```

Comment: Logcat is better to know about the exception..In which sentence you faced the issue ?

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304) at com.example.thetrial.QuizActivity$1.onClick(QuizActivity.java:46)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run

Answer (score 0):

You should not hard code the number of questions, especially since you appear to be off by one.  Use the length of the `List` to check out of bounds instead.

Change --

```
 if(qid<5){                  
     currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
     setQuestionView();
 }
```

to

```
 if(qid < quesList.size()){                  
     currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
     setQuestionView();
 }
```

Comment: IT WORKED! But how can I show the percentage score of the quiz? Please help. I'm only new in Java. :(

Comment: Not sure about showing it, it looks like you are starting a new `Activity` for that.  If you want to calculate it, divide your `score` variable by the number of questions and multiple by 100. `float percentScore = 100.0 * score / quesList.size();`

Comment: How can I randomize the order of my radio button? And how to unable the auto checked radio button? :(

Comment: That is a completely different question.  It would be best to open a new question for that.